# Jmeter | Load million Telephone numbers from DB and hit 1 rest point using multiple threads

Tags: jmeter

I have a requirement where I have to load 1 million Telephone numbers from database and once that data is retrieved, need to call one REST endpoint using multiple threads. So I will load the data once and once data is loaded, use same dataset to hit rest endpoints concurrently.

I am a newbee to Jmeter and I am not able to figure out how to create thread groups to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend

1. Using [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group) to load the data from the database, there add:

   - [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) to specify your database URL, credentials, etc.
   - [JDBC Request Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) to execute the query and save the results into JMeter Variables
   - [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to write the results into a CSV file

   Check out [How to Retrieve Database Data for API Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter) article for example implementation.
2. Using normal Thread Group to create the concurrent requests:

   - [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) - to load the numbers from the CSV file so each virtual user would use the new number on next iteration
   - [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to call your API